# How to subtract successive rows of a pandas dataframe with the last updated value

Tags: python

I have a time series data where I need to add a row based on the date the Stage column was last updated. And I have repetition of data: for example

```
Id    Date            Stage   

1   20-12-2013    Basic

1   20-10-2015    Basic

1   05-12-2018    Advanced

2   20-05-2019    Basic

2   15-12-2019    Advanced

3   20-01-2020    Advanced

4   20-10-2020    Basic

4   20-12-2020    Advanced
```

Expected Result :

```
Id  Date          Stage     Stage Changed Since

1   20-12-2013    Basic       NaN

1   20-10-2015    Basic       NaN 

1   05-12-2018    Advanced  05-12-2018 - 20-10-2015

2   20-05-2019    Basic       NaN

2   15-12-2019    Advanced  15-12-2019  - 20-05-2019

3   20-01-2020    Advanced    NaN

4   20-10-2020    Basic       NaN

4   20-12-2020    Advanced  20-12-2020 - 20-10-2020
```

So, basically when the stage changes within the same Id , I need to get the number of days since stage changed. And Stage Changed Since column should show that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

You could create 2 shifted down columns for `stage` and `date`, and do a comparison

```
d = {
    1: {'date': datetime(2010, 10, 10), 'stage': 'basic'},
    2: {'date': datetime(2010, 11, 10), 'stage': 'basic'},
    3: {'date': datetime(2010, 12, 10), 'stage': 'advanced'},
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

# created shifted columns
df['stage_lagged'] = df['stage'].shift(1)
df['date_lagged'] = df['date'].shift(1)

# compare values
df.loc[df['stage'] != df['stage_lagged'], 'stage_changed_since'] = df['date_lagged']

# convert the date column to a date type
df['stage_changed_since'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stage_changed_since'])

df = df[['date', 'stage', 'stage_changed_since']]
```

And you get

```
        date     stage stage_changed_since
1 2010-10-10     basic                 NaT
2 2010-11-10     basic                 NaT
3 2010-12-10  advanced          2010-11-10
```

Comment: Basically when the stage changes within the same Id , I need to get the number of days since stage changed. And Stage Changed Since column should show that .